# Add-ons or libraries for adding user comment functionality to an existing ASP.NET page?

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.NET site which I'd like to add page-level comments to without having to change everything over to a blog/CMS platform like BlogEngine.net, Wordpress, Umbraco, etc. Does anyone know of an add-on or library, either free or for-purchase, which can be added to certain ASPX pages to enable a stream of user comments at the end of the page?

The rest of the ASPX page needs to be able to have ASP.NET form controls, jquery and in some cases postback functionality I've written specific to the page which is why a simple blogging page is not enough as it means the blog engine owns the page aside from static content the site owner can enter.

Ideally there would be a way I could add a code snippet or user control to each ASPX page where I wanted comments and then they would show up and be managed independently on each page. I'd like to have the ability for users who post comments to be emailed when additional comments or replies are posted to their comment.

I am currently not locked into a particular authentication method so that is not necessarily a limiting factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems fun, I've not used it yet so I can't say if it works well or not.

http://developers.facebook.com/news.php?blog=1&story=198

Comment: Thanks, the link also mentioned Disqus and js-kit. Checked TechCrunch.com - I've always liked how their comments work - and it uses Facebook Connect. These 3 options are what I needed to get started. Thanks!